# Why does "- --" and "+ ++" and operate differently?

Tags: c++, increment, operator-precedence, decrement

Decrementation / Incrementation is a basic operation but it's precendence on `- --` and `+ ++` confused me. I'll use decrementation for illustration:

I have a set here of different styles of operating between `a` and `b`: [See it working here](http://ideone.com/wl3zZs)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int a=10, b=7;
int main() {
// - and -- opearator                         // Results:  Details:
    a = 10, b = 7; cout << a---b << endl;     //    3      a post-decrement        
    a = 10, b = 7; cout << a ---b << endl;    //    3      a post-decrement     
    a = 10, b = 7; cout << a- --b << endl;    //    4      b pre-decrement    
    a = 10, b = 7; cout << a-- -b << endl;    //    3      a post-decrement  
    a = 10, b = 7; cout << a--- b << endl;    //    3      a post-decrement 
    return 0;
    }
```

I understand that the `4` output came from the decremented `b` which is `7` that turned to `6` and is subtracted from `a` which is `10`.

Also, because of the other four statements, I thought the compiler treats all of them as `---` but behold, here comes the confusion of `- --` results. [See it working here](http://ideone.com/wl3zZs)

Comment: All the bits in the "Details after a statement" column are wrong. All of those decrement exactly one variable.

Comment: Try putting the operations in its own statement so the prefix/postfix doesn't confuse the results. E.g. `auto const x = a---b; std::cout << x << ", " << a << ", " << b << "\n";`

Comment: Also see the "goes toward" operator, [`-->`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator).

Comment: @hvd I mean Results I got from echo

Comment: The linked examples repeatedly print out the value of `a` while labeling it as "`b`". If you fix it so that it actually prints out the value of `b` you'll see that nothing is particularly surprising or confusing about the program's behaviour, and there's no difference between parsing of `-` and `+`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Parsing follows the **maximal munch rule**, so all statements minus the third are interpreted as `(a--)-b` which decrements `a` and returns its previous value (which was `10`).

The third one is `a-(--b)` which is a pre-decrement on `b`, so the new decremented value is returned.

Comment: @Daniel it didn't, how did you gather that it did?

Answer (score 2):

> But why didn't it decremented after it's statement?

Because the `--X` operator:

- first performs the decrement
- then returns the result of decrementing

So, there's no way that `--b` will 'decrement afterwards'. It always does it "before".

> Confusion

Look carefully at code and results: Everytime where `---` is written without spaces, the result is the same: three. Three is also the result for `-- -` case. Even with a pure guess, you could say that compiler parses it as `-- -`. In fact, it actually does it like that, because the C++ Standard requires it to do so. See comments about 'maximum munch' rule. Same follows for other multi-character operators, like `++`.

In the other case where you have split that into `- --`, the compiler had no other option: it had to treat it literally as `- --` because of the space in the middle. Just as `-- -`, this case is obvious and it's perfectly visible which part forms the `--` operator and the compiler must obey that.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I just tried to explain it in common words.

Comment: `--b` may decrement afterwards. The key point is that `--b` evaluates to the value `(b-1)` . There is no implied ordering of the side-effect.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because of the [Maximal Munch Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch). From Wiki:

> In computer programming and computer science, "maximal munch" or
>   "longest match" is the principle that when creating some construct, as
>   much of the available input as possible should be consumed.

From [Expert C Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131774298):

> The ANSI standard specifies a convention that has come to be known as
>   the  **maximal munch strategy**. Maximal munch says that if there's more
>   than one possibility for the  next token, the compiler will prefer to
>   bite off the one involving the longest sequence of  characters.

Answer (score 1):

That statement is equivalent to 10-6 = 4,
rest are equivalent to 9-7 = 3.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int a=10, b=7;
int main() {
    // - and -- opearator               //  Results:  Details after a statement:
    cout << (a--)-b << endl; a=10, b=7;   //    3       Both a and b decremented
    cout << (a --)-b << endl; a=10, b=7;  //    3       Both a and b decremented 
    cout << a- (--b) << endl; a=10, b=7;  //    4       Neither a or b decremented
    cout << (a--) -b << endl; a=10, b=7;  //    3       Both a and b decremented
    cout << (a--)- b << endl; a=10, b=7;  //    3       Both a and b decremented
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's post decremental, whence the confusion :)

Answer (score 1):

In this series of statements

```
cout << a---b << endl; a=10, b=7;   //    3       Both a and b decremented
cout << a ---b << endl; a=10, b=7;  //    3       Both a and b decremented 
cout << a- --b << endl; a=10, b=7;  //    4       Neither a or b decremented
cout << a-- -b << endl; a=10, b=7;  //    3       Both a and b decremented
cout << a--- b << endl; a=10, b=7;  //    3       Both a and b decremented
```

you forgot to include one more statement:)

```
cout << a --- b << endl; a=10, b=7;  //    3       Both a and b decremented
```

In all these statements

```
cout << a---b << endl; a=10, b=7;   //    3       Both a and b decremented
cout << a ---b << endl; a=10, b=7;  //    3       Both a and b decremented 
cout << a--- b << endl; a=10, b=7;  //    3       Both a and b decremented
cout << a --- b << endl; a=10, b=7;  //    3       Both a and b decremented
```

The compiler parses outputed expression as

```
a-- -b
```

that is it tries to extract the longest valid token.

The value of the postdecrement operator as for example `a--` is the value of its operand before decrementing. So in expression

```
a-- -b
```

the value of `a--` is 10 and the value of `b` is `7`. The difference is equal to `3`.

And you have the only expression with the predecrement operator

```
cout << a- --b << endl; a=10, b=7;  //    4       Neither a or b decremented
```

There the value of `--b` is the value of `b` after decrementing that is `6`. So you have `10 - 6` that is equal to `4`.

If you will substitute minus to plus in all these statements you will get the same effect

```
17
17
18
17
17
17  // this corresponds to my added statement a +++ b
```

So these operations - -- and + ++ behave in essense the same way.